# Laravel query on relationship with joined table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, one-to-one

I have a one-to-one relationship. My `jobs` table is connected to `user_jobs` table.

I have a join on that relationship to get the users data that is connected to the job.

This is my relationship inside the **Job** model:

```
public function client(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\ClientJob')->leftJoin('clients', 'client_jobs.client_id', 'clients.id')
    ->select('clients.id', 'client_id', 'job_id', 'name');
}
```

This part of the code works and I get the clients data.

**However I can't add a where clause on that relationship (specifically the name column that is fetched).**

This is the part of my code that tries to `search users by their name` column:

```
$jobs = Job::
    when($request->input('keywords'), function($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $keywords = $request->input('keywords');
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            $query->orWhereHas('client', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
            $query->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
            $query->orWhereHas('status', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
        });
    })
```

> This part is getting a **"Column no found"** error.

```
$query->orWhereHas('client', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
```

Anyone know how to get this query up and running apart from removing the join inside the model and moving it into the query above the where clause?

**EDIT**

This is my whole query:

```
$jobs = Job::
    when($request->input('keywords'), function($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $keywords = $request->input('keywords');
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            $query->orWhereHas('client', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
            $query->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
            $query->orWhereHas('status', function ($query) use ($keywords){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
            });
        });
    })
    ->with(['client','category' => function($query){
        $query->select('id', 'name');
    },'status' => function($query){
        $query->select('id', 'name', 'color');
    }])
    ->when($request->input('sort_by'), function($query) use ($request) {
        if($request->sort_by == 'desc'){
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }else{
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
        }
    })
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Try client.name

Comment: Neither client.name or clients.name works unfortunately.

Comment: Try Job::with('client')

Comment: Remove the `paginate()` method, so you get an unexecuted Query object.  Then do a `->toSql()` and a `->getBindings()` on it.  This will show you what SQL QueryBuilder would attempt to execute.  If the source of the problem isn't evident then, please post the result so we can dissect it further.

Comment: Are you sure they the column not found is coming from the client relationship?

Comment: Yes, I can display the name of the client in the view with $job->client->name, but i can't access the name column in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, too few points in reputation so writes here instead.
Perhaps include the ClientJob relationship in whereHas() like so

`orWhereHas('client.clientJob', function (...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the mistake is in the form that built the relationship. The difference between relationships with
Eloquent and Query builder

`public function client(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\ClientJob', 'client_id', 'id')->select('client_id', 'job_id', 'name');
}`